# How to test email logic with Play Framework

Tags: java, unit-testing, email, testing, playframework-1.x

I got an class that extends Mailer and would like to have automatic tests for that.

With mock mailer I can get the mail to console but how to test mail logic from the automated test?

(Is there something like [Mailer testing with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-testing)?)

br, Touko

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While writing this question, I found this link : [Testing mail sending by using Mock Mailer](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=150545144970035).

So, one can access mails mailed with Mock mailer with play.libs.Mail.Mock as follows:

```
String email = Mail.Mock.getLastMessageReceivedBy("joe@example.com");
```

The mail is returned as one string but that's better than nothing.

Though to share this since it took me a while to find this.

Comment: Note that from Play Framework >= 1.3.0, you can use Mail.useMailSystem, more details e.g. https://github.com/playframework/play1/blob/9285dcfbec25097b4a03e1b5b740301ce637b99f/framework/src/play/libs/Mail.java#L71