# How to access mocked email in Play 2.4.x

Tags: java, unit-testing, email, playframework-2.0, mocking

I'm currently trying to write some test for a small play (2.4.0) application. I need to get a link that I send in a mail (generated with database content), but I didn't find how to get access directly to the mocked email.

I know from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498878/how-to-test-email-logic-with-play-framework) that there was a way to do it for the play 1.x versions but I didn't find any equivalent. Any idea?